# Sub consulta em um único campo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Preciso criar um código onde faço o UPDATE de um campo sempre acrecentando um valor ao que já existe.

Exemplo de tabela supondo que já está populada:

```txt
ID | EMAIL | QUEMCURTIU
1  |a@a.com| 3, 46, 81,
```

Abaixo o usuário dono do ID 36 clicou para curtir:

```sql
UPDATE tabela SET QUEMCURTIU = QUEMCURTIU + "$id";
```

```txt
ID | EMAIL | QUEMCURTIU
1  |a@a.com| 3, 46, 81, 36
```

Até aqui tudo bem, porém o que precisaria agora era fazer um select baseado nesses valores separados. O que estou tentando é algo do tipo:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE QUEMCURTIU NOT LIKE %$id%
```

Porém dessa forma se possuir o número 14 e 144 dá errado.

Como poderia fazer para chegar no resultado esperado?

Comment: Dizem que quanto menos consultas melhor certo?(performance) seguindo essa ideia quero finalizar a minha ideia utilizando uma unica tabela, meu sistema utilizando 3  tabelas fazendo a mesma funcao esta funcionando, so estou procurando outros meios ( irei testar no benchmark sql o desempenho dos 2 tipos)

Comment: no caso ali o ID 36 é o do usuario que clicou em curtir , o ID 1 é de @dvd outro usuario | se o ID 1 clicar em curtir o ID 36 sera inserido no campo QUEMCURTIU  dele o seguinte -> 1, |  se o ID 24 clicar em curtir o ID 36 sera inserido no campo QUEMCURTIU  dele o seguinte -> 1, 24

Comment: exato porem estou me embaralhando com  o select que pesquisa parte de texto dentro do campo

Comment: sim esse codigo ai escrevi correndo na verdade esta somando, estou usando concat para inserir os ids, quanto a virgula e que tava pesquisando para realizar a consulta via um coringa

Comment: sim porem esse nao e o problema . o meu problema mesmo é a questao do SELECT

Comment: Teria que criar o padrão: `,3,46,81,36,`.. assim fica mais fácil de achar o valor com `LIKE '%,$id,%'`

Comment: O campo "QUEMCURTIU" teria que ter como valor default a vírgula, e vc só vai adicionando os valores com o update: `UPDATE tabela SET QUEMCURTIU = QUEMCURTIU + '$id,';`... o resultado será números delimitados por vírgula antes e depois, evitando a confusão de 14 e 144.

Comment: qual banco é ? você poderia usar um campo array também... ou fazer o que o dvd falou

Comment: @RovannLinhalis mysql , estou tentando pegar mais nao vai  $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email <> '$email' AND canaisquejaseinscreveu NOT LIKE ',%%,'  ";

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE FIND_IN_SET($id, QUEMCURTIU) = 0`

Ainda que funcione, o meu comentário na pergunta continua valendo. Se o seu argumento é performance, isso é muito pior do que normalizar o relacionamento corretamente, além de não ser uma função SQL padrão.